# why I cant open localhost:4500 in my browser

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, server

my output in terminal

```
at Function.handle (C:\Users\dream\Desktop\web\6- login\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:170:15)   
    at Server.app (C:\Users\dream\Desktop\web\6- login\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:39:9)
    at Server.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:956:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
```

my node js code

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "Ahd12332199",
  database: "nodejs",
});

// connect to the database
connection.connect(function (error) {
  if (error) throw error;
  else console.log("connected to the database successfully!");
});

app.get =
  ("/",
  function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(dirname + "/index.html");
  });

app.listen("4500");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your port is a string - remove the ""